# Fastest possible way to get Android Camera data

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to find out the fastest way to get data back from an android camera as I need to test a picture every 1ms. Is there a way to do this, or is this impossible?

So far I've tried `takePicture()` and 200ms was the fastest result between pictures. Over the past week I've also tried `onPreviewFrame()`, which managed 80ms. I have read every post relating to this topic on here and tried every solution for several weeks and I am unable to come any closer than 80ms - 160ms per frame on average using `onPreviewFrame()`.

Comment: Perhaps someone could help you find an alternative approach to your problem if you also explain why you need to access the camera 1000 times a second. Also, do the hardware specs of your phone's camera give an indication that this is even possible?

Comment: Most likely this will not be possible at all.  The camera hardware will only go for a certain maximum speed burst, around 10-12 shots per second.  The camera's sensor needs at least that much time to process the light it receives through the lens.  You may be able to go as far 15-20 shots if you lower the image quality.  On some higher-end devices, the camera may support full HD, in which case you may be able to get 60 shots per second - but that'll be an absolute maximum.

Comment: Thank you Aleks. Do you think it would be possible to capture video and then parse / decompress the resulting binary stream to get 1000 FPS?

Comment: Your target speed of 1ms would put it in the region of high-speed cameras - you won't manage that on a consumer phone. Another issue that Aleks mentioned is the light - even for high-speed cameras you need powerful spotlights to manage enough exposure.
Apart from that, you'd also need to be able to retrieve and process the images continuously at 1ms per photo - otherwise they'd pile up and you'd run out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is impossible to take a picture every 1ms with android camera, even if on the flagship smartphone Galaxy S4. The fastest way to get preview frame is to use `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(PreviewCallback)`. And you have to call  `addCallbackBuffer(byte[])` repeatedly as long as preview is active